# WPF binding CombobBoxItem base on property

Tags: wpf, combobox, binding

My `View Model` class:

```
class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
      private string name;       
      private bool isVisible;
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      public string PersonName
      {
          get { return name; }
          set
          {
              name = value;
              OnPropertyChanged("PersonName");
          }
      }

      public bool IsVisible
      {
          get { return isVisible; }
          set
          {
              isVisible = value;
              OnPropertyChanged("IsVisible");
          }
      }
    }
```

My Students `collection` that store all my `objects`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbStudents" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Students}"
          SelectionChanged="cbInterfaces_SelectionChanged"/>
```

So in some point i want to disappear several Students from my `ComboBox` so i just change `IsVisible` value to `False`.

Any idea how to do that using `XAML` ?

Comment: I do not think it's possible to do this only in xaml, without its collection being changed in ViewModel

Comment: the easiest would be to create a second collection with the first data that is visible: `ObservableCollection <Student> StudentVisible => Students.Where (x => x.Isvisible);` and add `OnPropertyChanged("StudentVisible ")` in `Students` property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have your Students collection return only visible students.

```
    //All students (visible and invisible)
    ObservableCollection<Students> _AllStudents = GetAllStudentsFromDataSource();

    //only visible students
    ObservableCollection<Students> _VisibleStudents = new ObservableCollection<Students>();

    foreach(var _s in _AllStudents.Where(x => x.IsVisible)){
         _VisibleStudents.Add(_s);
    }

    //your property
    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get{ return _VisibleStudents; } }
```

In the case of your check box toggling the visibility of students, your checkbox can be bound to a command like this:

```
<Checkbox IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckboxChecked}" Command={Binding ToggleStudents}" />
```

And your view model has an extra control for the checkbox toggle and the command:

```
    bool _IsCheckboxChecked = false;
    public bool IsCheckboxChecked { 
           get { return _IsCheckboxChecked;}
           set {
                  if(_IsCheckboxChecked != value)
                  {
                    _IsCheckboxChecked = value;
                  }
               }
      }

public ICommand ToggleStudents
{
    get;
    internal set;
}

private void ToggleStudentsCommand()
{
    ToggleStudents = new RelayCommand(ToggleStudentsExecute);
}

public void ToggleStudentsExecute()
{
     _VisibleStudents.Clear();
    if(_IsCheckboxChecked){
        foreach(var _s in _AllStudents.Where(x => x.IsVisible)){
          _VisibleStudents.Add(_s);
        }
      }
    else
    {
       foreach(var _s in _AllStudents.Where(x => x.IsVisible == false)){
          _VisibleStudents.Add(_s);
        }
     }

    OnPropertyChanged("Students");

}
```

Your xaml doesn't need to change.

Comment: But my XAML is binding with all the students and i have check box that change the IsVisible property from ture to false

Comment: You bind the checkbox to a command, and on the command you toggle the visibility of students